# how to log custom logging to Application Insights from Java

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-application-insights, logback

I am using Java and spring boot 3. I have followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=java to setup applicationinsights-agent. I can see the telemetry being logged to Application Insights.

```
ApplicationInsights.json
{
  "connectionString": "<Your Connection String>"
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationInsights.attach();
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
  }
}

//pom.xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.18</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now I want to add in custom logging info for my application package(com.example.demo) (not autoinstrumented telemetry data). According to document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config#autocollected-logging

> "Log4j, Logback, JBoss Logging, and java.util.logging are
> autoinstrumented. Logging performed via these logging frameworks is
> autocollected."

Here is my logback.xml

```
<property name="LOG_FORMAT"
    value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, America/Chicago} [%thread] [%-5level] %logger %method [%line] - %msg%n" />

<appender name="console"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${LOG_FORMAT}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>

<logger name="com.example.demo" level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```

But I don't see any log in Application Insights

```
    log.info("***************** DemoApplication start - info ************");
    log.debug("***************** DemoApplication start - debug ************");
    log.warn("***************** DemoApplication start - warn ************");
    log.error("***************** DemoApplication start - error ************");
```

In version 2, I added com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logback.ApplicationInsightsAppender to logback.xml. Now it is No longer needed since Logback is autoinstrumented in the 3.x Java agent. But I couldn't get it working. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Application Insights SDK` to log custom data to Azure Application Insights.

- Log custom events, metrics, traces, and exceptions can be logged with `TelemetryClient` class.

**Code Snippet:**

```java
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.EventTelemetry;

public class MyClass {
    private static final TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();

    public void myMethod() {
        EventTelemetry event = new EventTelemetry("RandomEvent");
        event.getProperties().put("MyCustomProperty", "MyCustomValue");
        telemetryClient.trackEvent(event);
    }
}
```

- Use the `Logger` interface to log custom data.

**Code Snippet:**

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyClass {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    public void myMethod() {
        logger.info("Logging the custom log message");
    }
}
```

- Add the `applicationinsights-logging-logback` dependency in pom.xml.

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

- Configure the `Application Insights SDK` to use the `Logback` logging framework.

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="aiAppender" class="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logback.ApplicationInsightsAppender">
        <instrumentationKey>YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY</instrumentationKey>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="aiAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**References:**

[Application Insights logging with Java](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-logging).

Comment: Documentation link doesn't work. Can you please update it?